# Getting ABI of both base contract and proxy contract

Tags: javascript, solidity, nft, ethers.js

This is an example - https://etherscan.io/address/0x769250862220d509fb9bed5f88d824c9fb74a833.

It is a proxy contract which I use for minting, the problem is it doesn't have `mint` function when I use `etherscan` API to get its ABI. `Mint` function is only available on base contract which is this one - https://etherscan.io/address/0x29d1ab5f6bab57708a1935df104d985f4611dad6#code

So my question is if there is any possibility to get maybe both ABI's or how do I know where should I get base ABI. I am using `ethers` library.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my concern, we cannot get abi unless the contract is verified in explorer, ethers will never give the abi, as that includes the contract source  to generate the same.

we have the api's from explorers,

https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/contracts#get-contract-abi-for-verified-contract-source-codes

this works for all verified contracts, also has a limit rate of requests,